# Stopping service explicitly

Tags: android, service

I have an app, which contains two activities and a service and a reciever, service is used to get the location updates all the time, i will start the service in the reciever for the first time, my requirement is, i need to stop the service when my application is in foreground (running), and i need to start the service when i application is stopped. among two activities initActivity is the first activity that get launched when application starts, and the homegridActivity id the second activity, i am giving the option in homegridactivity to exit from the application. below is the code where i am starting the service and stoping the service.

```
class initActivity extends Activity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.app); 
    System.out.println("VANDROID service status inside oncreate of init" );
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if ("com.vaayoo.android.service.VLocationFetchService".equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            Intent intent = new Intent( VUiHelper.getInstance().getApplicationContext(), VLocationFetchService.class);
            boolean result = ((Vandroid)VUiHelper.getInstance().getApplicationContext()).stopService(intent);
            System.out.println("VANDROID service status" + result);
            manager = null;
        }

    }

}
```

}
//second Activity

```
Class HomeGridActivity extends Activity
{
 protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    System.out.println("Homegrid activity onDestroy called");
    VUiHelper.getInstance().clearControlCache();
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if ("com.vaayoo.android.service.VLocationFetchService".equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            Intent intent = new Intent( VUiHelper.getInstance().getApplicationContext(), VLocationFetchService.class);
        ComponentName compname  =((Vandroid) VUiHelper.getInstance().getApplicationContext()).startService(intent);
       System.out.println("COMPONENT NAME" +  compname.toString() );
            manager = null;
        }
    }
}
```

}

I am stoping the service in oncreate on the initactivity and starting the same service in ondestroy of homegridActivity, the problem i am facing is, this is working only for the first time, if i close and launch the app multiple times, service is not stoping and starting, i found that, the service is running all the time. i have made that service as start_sticky so that is should not be killed by android runtime at any point of time, i should have full control on that service to stop and start. not able to find out why it is not working all the time, why it is working only for the first time. what i am doing wrong ? how to troubleshoot this? is it because of making service as start_sticky?

Comment: FYI "I need to stop the service" engenders the thought that you must be doing something strange to begin with

Comment: Have you tried putting the `startService` code in `onResume()` and the `stopService` code in `onPause()`?

Comment: I am not staringtservice in onResume() and stopping it in onPause(), bcoz, i know that oncreate will be called at any cost when an activity is launched, and on destroy when activity in stopped. i had put log and sop's, and monitored, i am getting  those log and sop's every time the activity is launched and closed. i am worried only about, why it is working first time and why not for the mutiple times?

Comment: Hey Kristoper, i am starting service in a broadcast reciever for the first time.. service is getting started first time without any problem in the reciever.

Comment: i know that calling stopservice() will terminate the service irrespective of how many times u call the startservice (). but i want to know what happens when the startcommand() is called multiple times ? will it start one more new service or interrupt the running service and start the same service again. i may get break through if some one answers this doubt.. help me plz..

Comment: i fixed the issue.. i was trying to get the stopped service using "RunningServiceInfo". Runningserviceinfo will be giving the info only about the service which are running.. so i was not getting the stopped service..